# Как добавить uint8_t параметр в uint8_t массив?

Tags: c, char, stm32, stm32cubeide, unsigned

Всем доброго времени суток. Уверен это простая проблема, однако я раньше избегал использования *char* строки. Так, что не могу понять причину.

### ЗАДАЧА:

1. Как правильно добавлять по одному ***uint8_t uart_buff*** в ***uint8_t uart_str[600]*** (с i=0)?

Все что мог я проверил, проблема именно в этом. Отдельно ***uint8_t uart_buff*** получает значение, а вот ***uint8_t uart_str[600]***  только первое. Остальное остается пустым.

### Идея была в следующем:

Считать байт типа ***uint8_t*** с циклического буфера. С каждым проходом через считывание, добавлять его в конец ***uart_str[..]***. Для того, чтоб в последующем ***switch->case*** просто вывести ***uart_str[..]*** на консоль. Переменная ***str*** задействована в дальнейшем декодировании так, что я решил сохранять входящие команды в отдельном массиве ***uart_str[..]***.

ПС: циклический буфер и ***FuncThatDecodeUART()*** работают нормально, это видно по результатам декодирования.

ПСС: код для STM32, но уверен причина проблемы не в этом.

```
void FuncThatDecodeUART(){
    
    ProtocolStruct msg;
    ProtocolStatus status;
    
    uint8_t uart_str[600];                                          ///< Save income command via Uart
    uint8_t uart_buf;                                               ///< Buffer for each iteration
    
    while(uart_available()){                                        ///< return: circular buffer has something!
    
        uint8_t str = uart_read();                                  ///< 1 uint8_t per call
    
        memcpy( uart_buf, str, sizeof(str));                        ///< FIXME: copy for STR security
        strcat( uart_str, uart_buf);                                ///< FIXME: append to UART_STR
    
        if(FuncThatCollectUint8ForDecode(str, &msg, &status)){      ///< return: 1 when MSG is assembled
            switch(msg.msgid){
                case REQUIRED_COMMAND:{                             ///< Required command found
                     debugPrintlnU8Arr(&huart1, uart_str);          ///< Print
                }
                break;
                case OTHER_COMMAND:{
                    // Ignore 
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    memset(uart_str, 0, 256);                                           ///< Clear for next FuncThatDecodeUART() call 
}
//------------------------------- debugPrintlnU8Arr(..) -------------------------------
// Custom Print


void debugPrintlnU8Arr(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t uval[]){
    HAL_UART_Transmit(huart, uval, strlen(uval), 100);
    char newline[2] = "\r\n";
    HAL_UART_Transmit(huart, (uint8_t *) newline, 2, 100);
}
```

Comment: Если честно, то я не совсем понимаю Ваш код. 1. Вы получаете 1 байт из функции uart_read. Далее этот байт при помощи memcpy копируете в uart_buf (? почему просто не копировать его так uart_buf = str). Дальше вы хотите добавить этот байт в uart_str при помощи char * strcat( char * destptr, const char * srcptr ); При этом передаете не указатель на строку, а сам байт. Вобщем какая то ерунда

Comment: Вполне возможно делать так: ' static int pos = 0; uint8_t buf = uart_read(); uart_str[pos++] = buf;' Далее после разбора команды указатель Pos обнулить